# How to position editbox's cursor in shoes?

Tags: ruby, user-interface, shoes

Shoes is very handy GUI tool. I would like to do a search form so that a user is helped to navigate through larger texts for editing. For this I need to move the cursor within an editbox element.

Here you'll see my question in code:

```
Shoes.app do

  stack do
    p=para "After pressing 'search' a question will arise"
    box=edit_box  
    box.text="One\nof\nthe\nmost\nstriking\ndifferences\nbetween\na\ncat\nand\na\nlie\nis\nthat\na\ncat\nhas\nonly\nnine lives."
    flow :margin_top=>0.1 do
      search=edit_line

      button("search") do
        pos=box.text.index search.text 
        y = box.text[0..pos].split.size-1 if pos

        if not y.nil?
          #For example if you searched "only" then 
          #cursor should jump/scroll to line 17.
          #
          #Anything there for cursor positioning, 
          #like: box.cursor=[0,y]
          #
          p.text="How can I move editbox's cursor in line #{y+1}?"
        else
          alert "'#{search.text}' not found"
        end        
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Is there is any way to change cursor's position of an editbox? If not, do you know an alternative way of implementation?

Comment: atomota, welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Shoes doesn't seem to provide any way to do that. These are the only methods defined on EditBox (it inherits from Native, which has several methods, but again, none to reposition the cursor).

```
rb_define_method(cEditBox, "text", CASTHOOK(shoes_edit_box_get_text), 0);
rb_define_method(cEditBox, "text=", CASTHOOK(shoes_edit_box_set_text), 1);
rb_define_method(cEditBox, "draw", CASTHOOK(shoes_edit_box_draw), 2);
rb_define_method(cEditBox, "change", CASTHOOK(shoes_control_change), -1);
```

http://github.com/why/shoes/blob/cea39a8bf9a5b7057b1824a9fab868d1f8609d69/shoes/ruby.c